# Tensorflow's provided linear regression example is giving bad results

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I'm following the [linear regression example](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/get_started) from the tensor flow get started tutorial (not the one using tf.contrib.learn) . While the provided example works, if I use any other data as an input to train on I always get the following printed out:

```
W: [ nan] b: [ nan] loss: nan
```

I have tried it with various different data sets. Even simple data sets like this one

```
# training data
  x_train = [32,53,61,47,59]
  y_train = [31,68,62,71,87]
```

I can implement linear regression on the data without any problem if I implement it only in numpy and get correct weight and bias values.

I have tried adjusting the hyperparameters but still no luck. It always returns nan

I have also literally copied the code from the site and just replaced the data values so I know there is no hidden typo. This has been driving me crazy. Please help.

Comment: Make sure your data has no nan values. If it has at least one nan value it won't work.

Comment: yes I have checked that! Even with the x_train and y_train arrays of length 5 as indicated in my question above, it returns nan.

Comment: Have you tried reducing the learning rate??

Comment: ok! I had tried learning rates from .1 to .0001 but apparently adding one more 0 did it! thanks! Though when implemented in numpy I was getting results with a learning rate of .01. Why would there be such a difference in the learning rate that works?

Comment: Learning rate depends on the gradient and the gradient is going to be much higher for such high values. That is why you normally have a normalization preprocessing step, where you clamp the values between [-1, 1].

Comment: thanks for the tip! will implement the normalization step.